# Formulating a nested list comprising elements in the same position from another nested list

Tags: python, list, nested, nested-loops, nested-lists

How can I take a nested list and re-formulate it into a new nested list in which:

- the first list of the new nested list, B, comprises the first element of all of the lists within the nested list A.
- the second list of the new nested list, B, comprises the second element of all of the lists within the nested list A.
- the nth list of the new nested list, B, comprises the nth element of all of the lists within the nested list A.

Examples are:

```
A = [[100,200,300], [400,500,600], [1000,1500,300]]
```

such that B becomes:

```
B = [[100,400,1000], [200,500,1500], [300,600,300]]
```

Of course, in reality A contains hundreds of lists not just three. So i need a method to automate this for large numbers of lists.

Comment: if the inner lists equal length, `B = list(zip(*(a for a in A)))`.

Comment: or just `B = list(zip(*A))` will also work. Alternatively `B = [*zip(*A)]` but I know some people don't love `[* ]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that all the inner lists have the same length, then

```
B = [[inner_list[i] for inner_list in A] for i in range(len(A))]
```

Otherwise you can additionnaly check if index i is not out of bounds for current inner list:

```
B = [
    [inner_list[i] if i < len(inner_list) else None for inner_list in A]
    for i in range(len(A))
]
```